# Spark Dataframe can not be saved altough savemode is set to overwrite

Tags: java, apache-spark

I had the problem that my spark dataframe could not be saved with the method `saveAsTable` although I called the method with the savemode `'overwrite'`. 
The reason therefore is that an exception is thrown:

> 'AlreadyExistingException'

Which has to be catched. This does not make any sense for me. My first intuition was that developers wanted to inform you that a table already exists that will be overwritten, but why do you have to catch an exception if you already intend to overwrite the existing content?!

Can anyone explain why you would force devs to catch an exception if that is there purpose what you intend to be an exception? Remark that the thrown exception is not a runtimeexception.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using and can you post the entire exception?

Comment: i am using cloudera with pre configured spark in version 1.3.

Comment: sorry i searched in my log files for the exception but i dont find it anymore. i will post the entire exception if i can experiment again on the cluster.